# Black screen after installing Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

I’m wiping my Windows 10 system with a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04 using a bootable USB. I boot up the .iso file and Kubuntu starts its installation process. It finishes the installation and says I need to restart my PC to finalize the install.

I click “Restart Now” and the PC goes into a black screen. It stays on the black screen and nothing changes. This is my second time installing with the same outcome.

Any ideas or solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Was there ever a message to 'Remove installation device and press ENTER'? If not, I would try removing the bootable USB.

Also, it might be worthwhile simply waiting a few hours for the black screen to go away. I installed Kubuntu 21.04 on my brand new laptop and the loading process took quite some time.